# Working with Eclipse DSF

Tags: eclipse, debugging, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-cdt, softune

I've been tasked with merging our debugger from softune with eclipse's debugger. i understand that the DSF is made exactly for this. however, there seems to be no instruction on how to actually use the DSF.

I've searched around for a tutorial, or example and have not been able to find anything related to this. anyone have any tips or ideas? I am able to control the softune debugger from a .dll. I am trying to incorporate this in to the debuggers framework now however have no idea where to start.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at the [DSF Tutorial](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.cdt.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fdsf%2Fintro%2Fdsf_programming_intro.html) in the Eclipse help

Comment: I have but it covers more of how DSF works and not how to use to make a debugger plugin that works with the debugger. the examples are more like simple apps that implement the DSF commands.

Answer (score 0):

I've been working with both Softune and Eclipse for quite some time but as far as I know, what you want is not possible.

As far as I know, Fujitsu/Spansion offer no way to interface with their debugger from outside of the Workbench.

Did you manage to overcome this softune limitation ? The DSF part looks like the easy part for me.

Comment: I did not, i was able to use the SiPI.dll to make a program that actually controled softune, it provides some basic commands that softune accepts, but nothing to the level i needed.

I can initialize the workspace, open projects, build, load target files, reset the debugger, get addresses from symbols, set break points to a line, write to memory, read memory, run and stop, and get the current debugger status.

maybe this was enough to get something working but it is beyond me.

these can be found if you expand the dll with a process explorer. and i got the parameters for each function call.